# Matlab plotting the shifted logistic function

Tags: function, matlab, plot

I would like to plot the shifted logistic function as shown [from Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20y%20=%20e%5E%28x%20-%206%29%20/%20%281%20%2b%20e%5E%28x%20-%206%29%29%20for%20x%20from%200%20to%2012).

In particular, I would like the function to be of the form

```
y = exp(x - t) / (1 + exp(x - t))
```

where t > 0. In the link, for example, t is 6. I had originally tried the following:

```
x = 0:.1:12;
y = exp(x - 6) ./ (1 + exp(x - 6));
plot(x, y);
axis([0 6 0 1])
```

However, this is not the same as the result from Wolfram Alpha. Here is an [export of my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihxrM.png).

I do not understand what the difference is between what I am trying to do here vs. plotting shifted sin and cosine functions (which works using the same technique).

I am not completely new to Matlab but I do not usually use it in this way.

**Edit:** My values for x in the code should have been from 0 to 12.

Comment: Could you provide us with images of your expected output and your current output? I'm not sure what "doesn't look the same" really means.

Comment: Expected output is in the first link to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20y%20=%20e^%28x%20-%206%29%20/%20%281%20%2b%20e^%28x%20-%206%29%29%20for%20x%20from%200%20to%2012). The output that I am getting is in the [export of my plot](http://i.imgur.com/Q5Bzm.png). I should add that I used x from 0 to 20 in the export of my plot, but I want to be able to plot for any values of t > 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`fplot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fplot.html) takes as inputs a function handle and a range to plot for:

`>> fplot(@(x) exp(x-6) / (1 + exp(x-6)), [0 12])`

[image: Function of interest]

The beauty of `fplot` in this case is you don't need to spend time calculating y-values beforehand; you could also extract values from the graph after the fact if you want (by getting the [line handle](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/line_props.html)'s `XData` and `YData` properties).

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I was looking for and more! For those interested in getting the x and y values from the plot after it is plotted, see [this article](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1RIH3C/index.html?solution=1-1RIH3C).

Answer (score 0):

Your input to Wolfram Alpha is incorrect. It is interpreted as `e*(x-6)/(1-e*(x-6))`. Use `plot y = exp(x - 6) / (1 + exp(x - 6)) for x from 0 to 12` in Wolfram Alpha (see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20y%20=%20exp%28x%20-%206%29%20/%20%281%20%2b%20exp%28x%20-%206%29%29%20for%20x%20from%200%20to%2012)) for the same results as in MATLAB. Also use `axis([0 12 0 1])` (or no axis statement at all on a new plot) to see the full results in MATLAB.

In reply to your comment: use `y = exp(1)*(x - 6) ./ (1 + exp(1)*(x - 6));` to do in MATLAB what you were doing in Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: I would like what is originally interpreted in WA to be plotted in Matlab.

Comment: @slikz: see my edit which shows how you can do that in MATLAB, but it doesn't look like a logistic function.

Comment: I'm not sure if the function in your edit works or not. [This is the output](http://i.imgur.com/sizV1.png) that I am getting now.

Comment: @slikz: that is the same as on your link in Wolfram Alpha. Use `axis([0 12 0.3 1.7])` in MATLAB to make them look more similar.